# How to trigger a JavaScript function after "Bootstrap: collapse plugin" transition is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to re-size `iframe` height after Bootstrap: `collapse` plugin transition is finished. Click event doesn't work because the transition is not finished yet, JavaScript gets the wrong height information. Any Idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to handle the hidden event on the collapse plugin.

[From Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

> hidden    - This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden
>   from the user (will wait for css transitions to complete).

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

As pointed by @Francesc in the comment for Bootstrap 3.0 we have to use

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: For new users, mind the bootstrap version, on 3.0 the name of the events is different: $('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
}).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bootstrap 3.0 its pretty easy. shown.bs.collapse is the event that is fired when the element shown transition is complete. I believe you are looking for something like this.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on("shown.bs.collapse", function(){
 //trigger content change
 //this code will be triggered when the collapse transition is completed 
 //that is your myCollapsible element will have 'in' in your class
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the collapse plugin, but in the documentation it says there is a callback called 'hidden' that should be called once the element transition has finished:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden', function () {
    // do something…
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Ramesh and yours answers are same. I had to accept one by using tak tik tuk method.